# How can I create a `mutation` which response void in appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, apollo-server, aws-appsync

I am using AWS appsync as grahpql server and I'd like to create a `mutation` API to response null value. So I need something like:

```
mutation{
   updateUser(name: String!): Void
}
```

But `Void` is not a scalar type in appsync. I have searched some solutions like [Is it possible to not return any data when using a GraphQL mutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737043/is-it-possible-to-not-return-any-data-when-using-a-graphql-mutation) but they are all about using apollo server. Is it possible to achieve null response in appsync?

Answer (score 0):

I used primitive as an alternative:

`mutation{ updateUser(name: String!): Boolean }`

Always return true if successful and false otherwise.